# Deploy VueJS project on GCloud AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, vuex

I'm building a VueJS app with Vuex and a NodeJS API to Gcloud AppEngine.

I've pushed successfully my API to appengine and it works perfectly.

Now the problem is VueJS. What should include in the app.yaml?

Already tried with

```
runtime: php55
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
```

But it pushed 19000 files which is really too big for AppEngine (10 000 max)

What files can be avoided? And how?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

You should build your vuejs project(probably `npm run build`) and only deploy the built files only(several files).

refer to https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html for details
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines